# Laplace's problem in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I am computing the Laplace's eigenvalue problem on the region $\Omega$ formed by the four vertices $(1,1),(1,2),(−1,2),(−1,1)$.

Consider the Laplace problem, $$-L u = \lambda u$$ where $$L = y^2 \Big( \frac{\partial ^2} {\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2} {\partial y^2}\Big)$$

with the Dirichlet boundary condition that $u = 0$ at $\partial \Omega$.

I have attempted the following

First I have specified the region in Mathematica.

```
\[CapitalOmega]= Polygon[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Then I have written the main part.

```
Clear@ℒ 
Clear@ℬ
ℒ[x_,y_]= y^2* D[u[x,y],{x,2}]+ y^2* D[u[x,y],{y,2}]; 
ℬ[x_, y_] = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True];
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-ℒ[x, y], ℬ[x, y]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 5];
```

But it gives some errors.

[image]

Please help me. Thanking in advanced.

Comment: Works for me in 12.2 on Windows 10Pro, outputting `{{25.8582,40.7532,64.6432,87.71,96.4144},{InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{-1.,1.},{1.,2.}}
Output: scalar

][x,y],InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{-1.,1.},{1.,2.}}
Output: scalar

][x,y],InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{-1.,1.},{1.,2.}}
Output: scalar

][x,y],InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{-1.,1.},{1.,2.}}
Output: scalar

][x,y],InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{-1.,1.},{1.,2.}}
Output: scalar

][x,y]}}`.

Comment: @user64494, sorry did not see your comment. I can delete my answer and you can have a go, if you want.

Comment: @user21: A trifle. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

Works just fine in 12.2:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Polygon[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 1}}];
Clear@\[ScriptCapitalL]
Clear@\[ScriptCapitalB]
\[ScriptCapitalL][x_, y_] = 
  y^2*D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + y^2*D[u[x, y], {y, 2}];
\[ScriptCapitalB][x_, y_] = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True];
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-\[ScriptCapitalL][x, y], \[ScriptCapitalB][x, y]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 5];
vals

{25.8582, 40.7532, 64.6432, 87.71, 96.4144}

Plot3D[funs[[2]], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

[image]

Comment: which method for 4th order PDE problems has been used in Mathemtica12.2.0, Finite Difference?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, I am not sure I understand the question. The method to solve 4th order PDE has not changed in version 12.2 - I hope that's what you are looking for.